Closed Form Solution of Oblique Shock Angle in terms of Flow Deflection and Freestream Mach Number
The oblique shock angle $\beta$ is determined by the following standard Theta-Beta- relations:
$$ \tan \theta = \frac{2}{\tan \beta} \frac{M_1^2\sin^2\!\beta-1}{M_1^2(\gamma+\cos2\beta)+2} $$
where $M_1$ is the pre-shock Mach Number, $\theta$ is the flow deflection angle, and $\gamma$ is the ratio of specific heats.

In order to find a closed form expression for $\beta$ as a function of $\beta = f(M_1, \theta, \gamma)$, the paper A Closed-Form Solution to Oblique Shock-Wave Properties makes the following, unexplained transformation:
$$ \sin^6(\beta) + b \sin^4(\beta) + c \sin^2(\beta) + d = 0 $$
$$ b = - \left( \frac{M_1^2 + 2}{M_1^2} + \gamma \sin^2(\theta) \right) $$
$$ c = \frac{2M_1^2 + 1}{M_1^4} + \left( \frac{(\gamma + 1)^2}{4} + \frac{\gamma - 1}{M_1^2} \right) \sin^2(\theta) $$
$$ d = - \frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{M_1^4} $$
Graphically, this does seem to be a valid transformation, but I was not able to reproduce this algebraic/trigonometric manipulation. What am I missing?
Additionally, the author claims that the general cubic solution is as follows:
$$ \sin^2 (\beta) = - \frac{b}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{b^2 - 3c} \cos \left( \frac{\phi + n \pi}{3} \right) $$
$$ \cos(\phi) = \frac{\frac{9}{2}bc - b^3 - \frac{27}{2}d}{(b^2 - 3c)^{3/2}} $$
where $n = 0$ corresponds to the strong solution, and $n = 4$ corresponds to the weak solution. It seems that this strong solution is valid, but the weak solution does not seem to line up.
I have plotted these here, for reference: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pgdc3pg9wc
I would appreciate any help this Stack Exchange might be able to provide. Thank you in advance.

To get to the sextic, you probably want to start with these steps:
\begin{align*} \tan{\theta} &= \dfrac{2}{\tan{\beta}}\dfrac{M_1^2\sin^2{\beta}-1}{M_1^2\left(\gamma+\cos{2\beta}\right)+2}\\
\\
\sin{\theta}\sin{\beta}\left[M_1^2\left(\gamma+1-\sin^2{\beta}\right)+2\right] &= 2\cos{\theta}\cos{\beta}\left(M_1^2\sin^2{\beta}-1\right)\\
\\
\left(\sin{\theta}\sin{\beta}\left[M_1^2\left(\gamma+1-\sin^2{\beta}\right)+2\right]\right)^2 &= \left[2\cos{\theta}\cos{\beta}\left(M_1^2\sin^2{\beta}-1\right)\right]^2\\
\\
\sin^2{\theta}\sin^2{\beta}\left[M_1^4\left(\gamma+1-\sin^2{\beta}\right)^2+4M_1^2\left(\gamma+1-\sin^2{\beta}\right)+4\right]&=4\cos^2{\theta}\left(1-\sin^2{\beta}\right)\left(M_1^4\sin^4{\beta}-2M_1^2\sin^2{\beta}+1\right)\\
\end{align*}
and then grind through to getting a sextic polynomial in $\sin{\beta}$.
I cannot answer "What am I missing?", because you have not shown your work.
The solution to the sextic is presented as a solution to a cubic in $\sin^2{\beta}$ so you'll have an ambiguity to resolve in the end.
The general solution the author presented appears to assume the cubic has 3 real roots.
I would encourage you to read these papers on the solution to the cubic:
Nickalls' geometric approach to solving the cubic
Roots of the cubic in terms of a complex hyperbolic angle
